# How would you make a test case for a method that takes a FileInputStream?

Tags: java, testing

I have to make a test case for a method that takes a FileInputSteam as a param:

```
public void loadContacts(FileInputStream inputFile) {
        if (inputFile == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("inputFile must not be null");
        }
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine().strip();
            int delimPos = line.indexOf('|');
            this.addContact(new Contact(line.substring(0, delimPos), line.substring(delimPos+1)));
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
```

I don't know how to test this so that everything is covered. If someone could point me in the right direction I would be greatful. I managed to pass the null argument with

```
@Test
    public void testForLoadContent() {
        ContactList testContactList = new ContactList();
        testContactList.loadContacts(null);
    }
```

But I don't know how to do the second part.

Comment: Take an `InputStream` instead. Then you can pass it either a FileInputStream or a ByteArrayInputStream

Comment: I can't edit the code, I have to make test cases on the code provided

Comment: Either create a temporary file and open a FileInputStream to it, or extend FileInputStream in a class that proxies a ByteArrayInputStream. In either case, add a helpful comment about why a sub-par solution became necessary.